# Elasticsearch term suggester return stemmed results

Tags: search, elasticsearch

why is the elasticsearch term suggester results are stemmed ?
when i do this query:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/posts/_suggest' -d '{
  "my-suggestion" : {
    "text" : "manger",
    "term" : {
       "field" : "body"
    }
  }
}'
```

the expected result should be "manager" but I get back "manag":

```
{
    "_shards":{
    "total":5,
    "successful":5,
    "failed":0
},
"my-suggest-1":[
    {
    "text":"mang",
    "offset":0,
    "length":6,
    "options":[
        {
            "text":"manag",
            "score":0.75,
            "freq":180
        },
        {
            "text":"mani",
            "score":0.75,
            "freq":6
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

**EDIT**

i found a solution for my problem: i added a standard analyzer to my query.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/posts/_suggest' -d '{
  "my-suggestion" : {
    "text" : "manger",
    "term" : {
       "analyzer" : "standard",
       "field" : "body"
    }
  }
}'
```

now the results are good:

```
{
    "_shards":{
    "total":5,
    "successful":5,
    "failed":0
},
"my-suggest":[
    {
    "text":"mang",
    "offset":0,
    "length":6,
    "options":[
        {
            "text":"manager",
            "score":0.75,
            "freq":180
        },
        {
            "text":"manuel",
            "score":0.75,
            "freq":6
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

but i've run to another similar problem with agregations:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "cities" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "location" }
        }
    }
}
```

the results i get are trimmed:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 473,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "cities": {
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "londr",
                "doc_count": 244
            }, {
                "key": "pari",
                "doc_count": 244
            }, {
                "key": "tang",
                "doc_count": 12
            }, {
                "key": "agad",
                "doc_count": 8
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more? (the mapping, sample of data etc)

Comment: @AndreiStefan i found a solution to my previous problem, but now i have the same problem with agregations. does agregations support adding an analyzer to thier query ?

Comment: My previous request still stands ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms aggregation works on "term" that are made from original text via tokenization and stemming. You need to mark field as "not_analyzed" in your index mappings to disable tokenization and stemming.

I never used suggesters, but it think that you need to disable stemming for that field, but enable tokenization. You can have two versions of field in index - one for search (tokenized and stemmed) and one for suggesters (tokenized, but non-stemmed).

Comment: to improve this solution, we can use [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/multi-fields.html) in order to have multiple analyzers for the same filed instead of duplicating it.